# d3v4 scatterplot - fixing the domain adding animations

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm trying to upgrade an old scatterplot chart -- but mapping the domain has become an issue where its not rendering the positions for the dots correctly.

//version 4 attempt
https://jsfiddle.net/z16u8j4c/1/

//old version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/oj2sg38z/2/

I tried to refactor the dataset so it could contain label information - for possible future legend generation.

```
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                  .range([ 0, width ]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                  .range([ height, 0 ]);
```

I've tried to fix it in my version by using d3v4 standards

```
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value[0]; })])
                  .range([ 0, width ]);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value[1]; })])
                  .range([ height, 0 ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `d3.max`. Your data is an array of object with values for different series. If you want to find the max for all values, you have to iterate over all data.values, so one way to do it is to get all values and flat it on array, then find its max.

```js
var x = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(s => s.value).flat(), d => d[0])])
  .range([0, width])

var y = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(s => s.value).flat(), d => d[1])])
  .range([0, height])
```